# What is the significance of editing questions on Stack Overflow when your changes you suggest are capital or bold fonts?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

I am asking this question in the context of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49884563/error-ts2339-property-getemployees-does-not-exist-on-type-employeeservice) question. I asked this question and got answer, but a user edited the question and changed "internet" to INTERNET and github to **Github**. Why do this?

Comment: Looks pointless to me. They may have edited the question to try to get it more views, since they answered it (only guessing). You can roll back the edit.

Comment: He wasn't thrilled about your capitalization, that's all.  The Internet does routinely get spelled with an initial capital, a company name always does.  All caps, meh, no.

Comment: Lack of proper capitalization and overuse of bold... Edit matches the style of the question and really should not be done - question looks equally poorly styled before and after the edit... The only redeeming part is no one needed to spent time reviewing this not very useful edit and no points gained...

Comment: Maybe it's time for an [automated answer bot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p85xwZ_OLX0).

Comment: another thing is there's badges for answering and editing questions. So the editor may have been gaming for that badge.

Comment: @YvetteColomb They have a few more edits that **boldface** product names:  https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49878505/revisions ,
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49877133/revisions . I'm not thrilled by these edits, but they do improve a few things. I think the user needs a little editing guidance. If, after some help, they insist on **pointless boldfacing**, then an edit suspension becomes reasonable.

Comment: @S.L.Barth ah **a misguided** bold user

Comment: Gotta love crapitalization and punctuashit.

Comment: We really, *really*, **really** need a bot that runs after every edit and automatically rejects those that are mostly or only capitalisation/punctuation/font face changes. Yes, this might discard useful changes, but if the post has to be edited afterwards to remove the unnecessary crap, it's wasting everyone's time. Better to discard the bad edit and warn the editor to do it *right* next time, maybe with some automated edit bans thrown in if said editors don't take the hint.

Comment: @IanKemp OTOH, sometimes a single comma can be invaluable, clarifying a post significantly. I won't be able to find examples, but I did see this once or twice. I've also edited for emphasis only quite a few times, in good faith I assure you. IMO it's better to allow pointless  harmless edits than to forbid useful ones. Maybe this bot could alert the mods instead.

Comment: @WillNess Or it could alert just a select group of dedicated reviewers. It could post in a chatroom dedicated to the purpose.

Comment: Maybe such "simple" edits shouldn't count towards the badge... Yes, I know it would be difficult to create such criteria but might be worth a look.

Answer (score 36):

Writing and editing on Stack Overflow should not be particularly different from standard formal or technical writing. The edits were wrong because they were not compatible with that approach.

Fixing case is fine, as long as the case is correct. All-caps is fine for acronyms (JSON, PHP, etc) but not otherwise. GitHub is a brand name and has a camel-case upper-case letter in it.

The word "internet" is a proper noun, and so is fine to give it an initial capital, but I think it has fallen into such common usage that this does not matter too much. I do not correct "internet" or "Internet" either way. However, all-caps is definitely incorrect. (As an aside, it is common to understand all-caps in electronic communications as shouting, so inappropriate usage here would just add further confusion.)

Good writing generally *never* uses bold in paragraph text. It is quite common for writers and editors on Stack Overflow to embolden things way too much, to the degree that the post becomes less readable. Keywords absolutely do not need to be emphasised in this way.

Comment: This answer could be used in our FAQ

Comment: I really want to change that _never_ to **never**, but I don't think it's appropriate to edit my joke into your answer, so I'll just leave this stupid comment instead.

Comment: @Don'tPanic: heh! I had to stop myself from adding a joke to a question on the main site asking about _crone jobs_. I was wondering if black cats and cauldrons were involved, but I think the joke might be lost in translation...

Comment: Probably so. Maybe they were just trying to satisfy spellcheck, and decided it probably wasn't "corn job".

Comment: Actually never might be underestimating the truth. Just today I looked up "Effective Java" and there were whole sentences printed bold and I remember that it was totally worth it.

Comment: My sort of `default` comment `for` marking `random` phrases with `tick` is `to` mark all common `keywords` `in` the comment as `code`, ending with `do` `not` `do` `this`. `Not` everyone gets `it`.

Comment: @usr2564301: my response to an outbreak of txtspk is 2 rspnd n knd 2 da d gree no1 knos wot ur tlkn abt `:=)`

Comment: afaik (forgive my ignorance), there is no exact guide for editing. So, usually editor learn it by experience and make an edit by how he/she thought sufficient and acceptable.

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך: yes. Ideally it is experience they bring from elsewhere - one cannot hope to learn grammar, punctuation, formatting and succinctness by looking at other people's edits (or jumping in the deep end and guessing!)

Answer (score 4):

The answer by [halfer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366232/1536976) leaves nothing to be desired in explaining why such edits are wrong and how to edit in such cases instead, but it doesn't explain why someone would propose such edits, which is what this question is asking.

The edit history shows that the member suggesting this edit has sufficient reputation to not take part in the edit review process nor gain additional reputation from editing. One could assume that they know how to edit and that they actually wanted to improve the content, because why else spending the time and even doing something right (the capital I for example).

However, the edit failed, so at least one assumption is likely to be wrong. Either there are members with sufficient reputation who still don't know what a good edit is, or they deliberately want to make questions worse.

It would like to believe it was insufficient knowledge.

Comment: Yup. I checked a few random recent edits by that same person – it does not look like something done out of habit. Really, I have no idea what the reason was to do it in the post under discussion.

Comment: @usr2564301 Some users genuinely believe that **boldfacing parts of sentences** makes a post better.

Comment: @S.L.Barth yes some of us genuinely do.